# Is there any way to see actual application error in a website hosted in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

A legacy .Net webform application is hosted in IIS is running fine in old server having .Net framework 2.0 in it. I don't have source code of the application. I have just existing published DLL which i have copied from old server to a new server having .Net 4.7 framework by default and hosted it in new server's IIS.

While browsing the application, it is showing an default configured Error.aspx page which developers may have configured. So, in case of any error the application will navigate to Error.aspx page.

I am not able to figure out the actual .net error.

How can i get the actual error or is there any way to debug that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find errors in iis log (default path is %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles).

Also you can enable detailed error message in browser. [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers/)

Comment: I have enabled detailed error message in browser by following the  steps in the Link.  I don’t see any detailed error message by configuring both highlighted options. It redirects to the same custom error page even when I access the website from local or remote.

Comment: @semwal Have you tried to check iis log? Also try to see if there is something in event viewer. There is also a possibility that you need to register dll.

Comment: Yes, i have tried to check iis logs but could not find anything in the logs below:         
%SystemDrive%:\InetPub\IISLOGS\W3SVC1
%SystemDrive%:\InetPub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles